# Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in _drupal_http_use_proxy() (line 1100 of /var/www/html/includes/common.inc)

Tags: forms

Whenever I add any content on my website, I get this warning.

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in
>   _drupal_http_use_proxy() (line 1100 of /var/www/html/includes/common.inc)

I am not sure why it does that, and how do I solve it?
Can anyone help?

PS: I don't know what tags should I use for this question.

**EDIT1:** Executing

> dpm(variable_get('proxy_exceptions'));

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code for _drupal_http_use_proxy

```
function _drupal_http_use_proxy($host) {
  $proxy_exceptions = variable_get('proxy_exceptions', array('localhost', '127.0.0.1'));
  return !in_array(strtolower($host), $proxy_exceptions, TRUE);
}
```

The status message warns that $proxy_exceptions is not an array.

You can configure this setting on your settings.php file, this way:

```
$conf['proxy_exceptions'] = array('127.0.0.1', 'localhost');
```

Have you changed this variable to anything other than an array?

```
 $conf['proxy_exceptions'] = '127.0.0.1'; // For example
```

Maybe there is a contributed module which do this...

Try to insert a dpm on $proxy_exceptions or execute this on /devel/php  to show the value of this variable:

```
dpm(variable_get('proxy_exceptions'));
```

If you want to reset this variable:

```
variable_set('proxy_exceptions', array());
```

or

```
variable_del('proxy_exceptions');
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. I have checked my settings.php file and I have this data but it is commented by default and I haven't changed anything. Here is the data `# $conf['proxy_server'] = '';
# $conf['proxy_port'] = 8080;
# $conf['proxy_username'] = '';
# $conf['proxy_password'] = '';
# $conf['proxy_user_agent'] = '';
# $conf['proxy_exceptions'] = array('127.0.0.1', 'localhost');`

Comment: Have you checked what is the value of this expression: dpm(variable_get('proxy_exceptions')); on /devel/php

Comment: I have installed the devel module now, I don't know how and where to execute it? Can you guide me please?

Comment: yousite.com/devel/php

Comment: I have edited my question, please check the edit1

Comment: Then reset the variable: variable_set('proxy_exceptions', array());

Comment: What do you mean by that? Should I write this in setting.php?

Comment: Execute it on /devel/php

Comment: I executed, It gave the same result as above in edit 1 but with 1 tick and blank text.

Comment: Yes, but the variable now must be an array. Has the warning gone?

Comment: yeah it looks like it has gone, but how did you do that? Can you explain it to me please?

Comment: The proxy_exceptions variable was corrupted on some point. You have reset this to a proper array() value.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't solve why I used to get the error messages, but I hid the errors and warnings for the everyone except admin using [Disable Messages](https://drupal.org/project/disable_messages) module. It's quite good, all I had to do is install the module, and change the permissions according to roles.

I will update my answer if I found the way to solve this warning.